# write images into a folder with a similar name as input files

Tags: python, image, image-processing, opencv

I have a directory of images, I am trying to do some image processing on them and write the result images into a different folder with an extension to their original name.

**My question is:** how do I write the images with a name similar to their original names?
Here is the code that I wrote:

```
img_dir="/path to original folder/images"
data_path=os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files=glob.glob(data_path)
data=[]
    
i = 0
for f1 in files:
     img=cv2.imread(f1)
     data.append(img)
    
    #####################################################################
        #############Image processing part
    ###################################################################
    
         path = '/path to new folder/'
         cv2.imwrite("{}{}_{:07d}.jpg".format(path,f1.strip(".jpg"), i), result)        
         i+=1
```

Comment: you can use `format`as `cv2.imwrite("{}result_{}_{:07d}.jpg".format(path,f1, i), result)`

Comment: sorry, this does not work, I just want to write it with the original name (numbers)+ extension. I do not want to add any "result" to it.

Comment: You suggest that you want to add a extension to the original name.  An "extension" is normally the 3+ letters that trail the file name (after the ".").   And it looks like you want to keep this intact.   Instead, it looks like you want to insert a fixed number of digits to the name.   Your approach looks like it should work, although I wouldn't try to  include the path name in your file name.  Use "join" instead" (unless you literally want to include the directory name in the file name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I missed one point. As you are using `files=glob.glob(data_path)`, the f1 has the full path.

As a result, f1 has to be split from the path.

Now you can try this:

```
img_dir="/path to original folder/images"
data_path=os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files=glob.glob(data_path)
data=[]
    
i = 0
for f1 in files:
     img=cv2.imread(f1)
     data.append(img)
    
    #####################################################################
        #############Image processing part
    ###################################################################
    
         path = '/path to new folder/'
         cv2.imwrite("{}{}_{:07d}.jpg".format(path,f1.split("/")[-1].strip(".jpg"), i), result)        
         i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

A detailed answer would be;

you can use `format` to concatenate string, integer, float, boolean, etc with out converting to string using `str`.

```
cv2.imwrite("{}result_{}_{:07d}.jpg".format(path,f1, i), result)
```

each `{}` is for each of the values in order for `path`, `f1` and `i` in `format()`. The first one is for `path`, the second one is for your original file name (`f1`). And the last one is for `i`. Here as you want to have 7 digits, you add `:07d` then it takes `i` and convert to `0000001`. If i is `101`, then it converts to `0000101`.

**Note:** if `f1` has extension like `jpg`, you can simply use:

```
cv2.imwrite("{}result_{}_{:07d}.jpg".format(path,f1.strip(".jpg"), i), result)
```

Comment: I just want to write it with the original name (numbers)+ extension. I do not want to add any "result" to it.

Comment: `cv2.imwrite("{}/{}_{:07d}.jpg".format(path,f1.strip(".jpg"), i), result)` this has to work then.

Comment: Could you please write your final code here? or update your code above.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following variables;

```
f1 = "00008_8_007004.jpg"
path = '/path to new folder/'
i = 1
>>> "{}{}_{:07d}.jpg".format(path,f1.strip(".jpg"), i)
'/path to new folder/00008_8_007004_0000001.jpg'
```

Now `_0000001` is added at the end of your original file name.

Comment: Thanks but I just want this part: "00008_8_007004_0000001.jpg", not the path though. It still does not work.